# DTO validator that aligns runtime type checks with compile time annotations

Tags: typescript

I am using [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) to generate a REST client.
Due to the OpenAPI definition the types of the client are mostly of the shape

```js
class Y {
  readonly b?: boolean | undefined;
  readonly v?: object | undefined;
}

class Z {
  readonly b?: boolean | undefined;
  readonly w?: object | undefined;
}

class X {
  readonly n?: number | undefined;
  readonly s?: string | undefined;
  readonly b?: boolean | undefined;
  readonly y?: Y | undefined;
  readonly z?: Z | undefined;
}
```

where all members are optional.

Because of this I would like to validate that some of the values are indeed not undefined, and also that their runtime type is correct (the generated client doesn't check it)

```js
  validate(x, "b", "boolean");
  validate(x, "s", "string");
  validate(x, "y", Y);
```

The first part is to strip away the optionality of the types using:

```js
type NonNullableProps<T> = T & { [P in keyof T]-?: NonNullable<T[P]> };
```

For the primitive types I got to a point where typescript allows me to autofill / check the claimed runtime type, e.g. `validate(x, "s", "number");` will give me an compile time error.
However, trying the same on types doesn't work, e.g. `validate(x, "y", Y);` since Y is compatible with all other generated DTO classes that have all members optional.
In my [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGcFNNALAXeAHcAuEATSA3AdPAe2AGsAnAVwFslJ5gBzSAO0lIEsBjAWngE8au9cgENSGLmyY9+kcB3ZJ4XAEwBWABwAbALAAoSfFYAzYRxh8aAWWFJQAbz2gI8dk3qpnr+gG5HoJlQARqweAZTBpL66ToEEBJqQwkwesfGJTFEAvnoWMADCmsLg4AA8ACoAfKAAvP6QAO6gABS4raL0aKBJvADaALoAlDVVZVG5oACCTLwFReA1oLPFJd0VYzKgAArslGzwbNiQAPKkeQRM4C7kHISkC1MzhcWgAD6gxJC8BEagudZIUT0IFAkiMrF+sBgQlEWAwvw2RlIBEoXQgNA4bCMnFAHCKMG+Wx2ewOx1O50uFBuBFIOQ2AHERGJIBgyjJyqBIAAPQxMDDzbZsXb7Q4nM4XK5U0hVWplDnc5h8+x1RotNqkDoebr9AYeUHggCqoGy0VAAH5QPq-B5ZVyeYqPl8fn8bH5zc6kD0yn0rXVDpE9HouUhqfBQEZyEwbmxzvCaAyYezbQr+UThaSxRTrrcKk0CB4I8QmAR6kwADQ4p7gABywkokGtOtABBB83jTJZbMq9j8HHJoc0BFxmgFQpJor7lNuHhHxJFZPFk+pCw4lZrdaiTkxzVyBIHQ5nafHC6zS+qZ9AACIKZJ6Behg4TU5SLRyKQmLHIATm2fanvhMPUzHedM0lDcjT8Z94Ffd9m0kS4kjMXdB3-A8gIzCVbiyANdHGKtzirchNEKQIEm2AgUHKaVQFlAAyJUek2EF3wdAkvS4U0PDwpgCKI4QSMgcoGL6KpMkBHCNnQxdSBKI45TteYCECAArSAbnLABpOTk3eT4CSOKiuJ44jSKRCj9J6dS+i03l5mvNxXUvOzbx9QzCOMyAyLMioLKspMbP8IJWAci8wgiC8XPwty+JM8jSnMyzrMVVIEiSYLkvScKTQ8JZSlc3j+M83LIvymKvJ8io1mwoMQzDCMoxjbB-zYDBhEMRN5X8xSVLU0BNL8+1dJ+MpyzyRL5kkk9pOG3qKqaPwuutUs-AdDx1KWk1cic7K9HvPwtyaCMsCxFg4R-JtlKGeBYCRRoWEaABRUgkVIJoLy61TQ0IUBGs0ZrWpgNh5kOyBjuZO8wP2gIiJqc8usu67i2VUBHue173puX5mx+v7DBbAKiPBvafiaExNCgGHagdJjzqU3bHwhG6kZR6kmgAA3R0MABI7AAKQAZSOKtcCczFeFzC7MlADACFkfwCFDXsmHgYRJB03hQAAcm5h1Mg11mBjA40nEVy5vv-cgYFqLqegdPoIeJqHNBhs3NAtumnCcK7Gbu5GnpZ1mqa1uwdY1vGi1Df8B3qZlMdAYJ8c0fXDaJ5oAEJcjbDAmh+i3y02lwbwGd2Pa9xGfeZl6A8+TXtc+XWw-lpsnQ2IP868XWk78I3QEg6CXYt1OsN0PQVzmUAAE1uxNZ9hGlphNHVwIOLjuIUvfN5gdBjAwJnueF++5eOdeUBN8kZkh5HytQAALSnp9Ej3xfl-SpJj9Pk6d4f859-qQ-lI+t+vIQZn23noY0l8x4AA0749y-vPdWTBl6hXBBvIBW9P6z2-urcAy8nKAKOiAjBj847P1XukfBwCP4QTgfvXgy9J6oIIVQ6eND1YAC9l630YZQ8+YDsIm1DJyH6Cwmicg8JAoY1QqgPicNjFqhhRHlgvIEC8SiX5MEJiaOR-1FGOVUY5AubhNGyKavIyAuiLy8H0ePA2fhtEKM5Eoth1jbG6FEkAA) I strip all optionality away, but the problem is that Y in this case is referring to the constructor, which returns an object of type Y; but at the same type I want only allow for constructors whose return type is compatible with NonNullableProps.
If I remove that restriction for the constructor, then Z is compatible with Y and ts will accept `validate(x, "y", Z);`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://github.com/flix-tech/fp-ts-type-check ?

Comment: @urmaul your lib is nice, but it requires to define in your syntax what i will expect; in my case NSwag defines that already for me, but doesn't validate it. The validate function in the playground will allow me to write a validator for runtime execution, that is also checked at compile time to adhere to the contract as defined by OpenAPI / NSwag